# Query custom post type with custom field and order ascending by custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I'm trying to figure out why this won't display a list of all wines in ascending order. From what i understand it seems this was the correct way to do it. It displays all the wines correctly on the page, but it doesn't order them.

```
            query_posts(array( 'post_type' => 'wineinput_custom', 'meta_key' => 'wine', 'showposts' => -1,'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'categories',
        'terms' => $subcategory3->term_id,
        'field' => 'term_id',

            )
        ),
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC' )
        );
```

Custom Taxonomy: categories.
Custom post_type: wineinput_custom
Field to order it by: wine.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this function to your function.php file,

```
function orderby_custom_fields( $orderby )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $orderby = "$wpdb->postmeta.meta_value ASC";
    remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'orderby_custom_fields' );
    return $orderby;
}
```

and now add this query_post data in your file,

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'wineinput_custom',
    'meta_key' => 'wine',
    'showposts' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array( 
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'categories',
            'terms' => $subcategory3->term_id,
            'field' => 'term_id'
        )
    ),
);
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'orderby_custom_fields' );
query_posts($args);
```

Hope this will help you...!!

Comment: I think i may be using this loop wrong... i set it up like this however, it doesn't seem to query anything... It's just coming up blank. http://pastebin.com/FhLiTxyW. Is this correct @Akshay? specifically, i don't need the subcategory bit. Using this does make the desired effect, however it does it for each subcategory. So it's a few different a-z's. How would i make a loop which encompases all entries in wineinput_custom?

Comment: If You want all "wineinput_custom" posts than remove "tax_query" part from arguments...

Comment: I am a moron. Can't see the wood for the trees as they say. Thanks a bunch!